# Telerik RadEditor working issue under VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, telerik

I've a SharePoint portal for tracking questions in a list. When I open an list item in IE8 Telerik Editor works fine. But if I open this page inside VS2008 in browser mode this control starts to do unexpected actions.

It's the Telerik RadEditor for Sharepoint v. 5.3.2.0.

Is it a bug of VS2008 or a bug of Telerik RadEditor?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Telerik RadEditor in SharePoint portal
2. Create a List with Rich editing field and create a new item
3. Paste or type a text into Rich editing field and save changes
4. Open VS2008
5. Click on any link in start page to open browser window
6. Open created list item in VS in editing mode
7. Mark a part of text in Rich editing field
8. Marked text disappears. Undo button of control shows some paste actions

Answer (score 0):

Try a newer version of the MOSS RadEditor (e.g. 5.5x). I tried with that and saw no problems when browsing from VS 2008.

Comment: But I haven't a license for a newer version. Only for 2008.3 (5.3.2.0) purchased a year ago.